# Globally setting timezone in go by setting Local

Tags: go, timezone

Related to [Setting timezone globally in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363451/setting-timezone-globally-in-golang)

In `zoneinfo.go` you can find the following

```
// Local represents the system's local time zone.
var Local *Location = &localLoc
```

which suggest that you have a global modifiable Local, and you can set it. By setting it, should it have effect to timezones?

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to use DI. Put all of your TZ-handling code in one place, and depend on a configured value (rather than a global state). This will also avoid bugs when using other libraries that depend on the actual local time zone (i.e. logging libraries).

Comment: You can see in the code that Local is just a pointer to another value that you cannot change. Making the two inconsistent is just asking for trouble. Don't do it.

Comment: Then why it is not a `const`?

Comment: @pihentagy Because a) its value is not a compile-time value, b) there are no pointer constants in Go.

Comment: You are not supposed to change this because a lot of things depend on it and there is a real risk of race conditions (speaking from experience). Golang docs have been updated to mention that since the time you've asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `time.Local` does have an effect on the `time` local time zone.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now().Round(0)
    fmt.Println(now, time.Local)

    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Atka")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    time.Local = loc

    now = time.Now().Round(0)
    fmt.Println(now, time.Local)
}
```

Output:

```
2019-07-16 10:45:41.263418395 -0400 EDT Local
2019-07-16 05:45:41.263530699 -0900 HDT America/Atka
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/XBxO2toH-SJ