# Golang: fork process with custom timezone

Tags: go

In Golang is it possible to fork a child process and force it to use a shifted timezone from UTC? For instance, my server's timezone is UTC, and I want the forked process to use UTC+5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting timezone globally in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363451/setting-timezone-globally-in-golang)

Comment: Windows and Linux (cross-compatible)

Comment: On which operating system? And what you exactly mean by forking a child process? In case of `exec.Command()` you can modify TZ environment variable of that command before running it.

Comment: It's precisely what @maerics posted as answer. Process is tz aware, it works on Windows but I don't know Linux...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to this question will give you more details ([Setting timezone globally in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363451/setting-timezone-globally-in-golang)) but ultimately you can simply set the `TZ` environment variable and then execute the command:

```
cmd := exec.Command("myprogram")
cmdtz := "TZ=America/New_York"
cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), cmdtz)
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: It seems to work on Windows OS, but will it do on Linux?

Comment: Yes, Linux also uses the `TZ` environment variable - https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html